# How to call in C# a DLL function (C++) which uses a pointer as a parameter?

Tags: c#, c++, interop, pinvoke, dllimport

I'm trying to call a DLL function (written in C++) called Function_A(Class1* input_class) in C#. This is the class I've declared in C#. I've read about using the ref keyword somewhere in the Function_A declaration but am unsure. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
[DllImport("The_DLL.dll")]
public static extern int Function_A(Class1* input_class);

public struct Class1
{
        int varA;
        int varB;
}

public struct Class2
{
        class1 class1_A;
        class1 class1_B;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
        Class2 a = new Class2();
        Function_A(...);
}
```

Comment: You will need to know the calling convention of `Function_A`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/using-cpp-interop-implicit-pinvoke?view=msvc-160

Comment: Depends very much on what the types actually are. We don't know that because you didn't include it.

Answer (score 1):

```
[DllImport("The_DLL.dll")]
public static extern int Function_A([In, Out]Class1 input_class);

[DllImport("The_DLL.dll", EntryPoint="Function_A")]
public static extern int Function_A2(ref Class1 input_class);


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Class1 //a bad name for a struct but hey...
{
        int varA;
        int varB;
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
        Class1 x = new Class1();
        Function_A(x); // your struct is marshalled so that changes by the external function are marshalled back
        Function_A2(x); // your struct is marshalled so that changes by the external function are NOT marshalled back
}
```